# Jacoco Jenkins plugin with Kotlin

Tags: jenkins, kotlin, jacoco

I want Jacoco plugin to post CodeCoverage on Jenkins build report, i had  prepare stage in job

```
stage('JaCoCo') {
    sh './gradlew testProdDebugUnitTestCoverage'
        jacoco(execPattern: '**/build/jacoco/testProdDebugUnitTest.exec', classPattern: '**/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/prodDebug', sourcePattern: '**/src/main/kotlin')
}
```

However i still get 0%, when locally generated report show 8%

Comment: Maybe there is something in Jenkins build log?

Comment: `Number of found exec files for pattern app/build/jacoco/testProdDebugUnitTest.exec: 0` which is strange becouse on local after runinng test i get exec file on that location